# How to check if a string contains a string from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to check if a string the user inputted contains one of the strings in a list.

I know how to check if the string contains **one string** but I want to know how to check if a string contains either this string, or that string, or another string.

For example, if I am checking the user's input to see if it contains a vowel.. there can be 5 different choices when we're talking about vowels (a, e, i, o, or u). How can I check to see if the string the user inputted has one of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> vowels = set(['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'])
>>> inp = "foobar"
>>> bool(vowels.intersection(inp))
True
>>> bool(vowels.intersection('qwty'))
False
```

Comment: This works, but there was another answer that showed any(), which also worked. Could you tell me why I should use .intersection() over any()?

Comment: @JasonDecastro For your example `any` is better, sets can be useful when the size of the set vowels is huge, in that case you can both `any` and `sets` together to get an efficient solution as sets provide O(1) lookup.
BTW `set.intersection` returns a new set containing the **unique** common elements between `vowels` and `inp`, bool() on it returns True when the length of the returned set is > 0. And `any` just return True/False.

Answer (score 3):

Using [any](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
>>> vowels = 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'

>>> s = 'cat'
>>> any(ch in vowels for ch in s)
True
>>> s = 'pyth-n'
>>> any(ch in vowels for ch in s)
False
```

Comment: Why choose any() over .intersection()?

Comment: @JasonDecastro, That only works for single character strings.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
NameError: name 'any' is not defined <- what's wrong in here, python 2.4.3

Comment: @jester112358, `any` is available from Python 2.5.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic logic you want:

```
def string_checker(user_input_string, vowels):
    for i in vowels:
       if i in user_input_string:
          return 'Found it'
    return 'Sorry grashooper :('

print string_checker('Hello',('a','e','i','o','u'))
```

The short cut way to do this is by using the built-in `any()` method; which will return true if *any* of the items in it returns a *truth value*.

Here is how it would work:

```
any(i in user_input_string for i in vowels)
```

The difference is that instead of returning a custom string, this method will return `True` or `False`; we can use it the same way in our loop:

```
if any(i in user_input_string for i in vowels):
    print('Found it!')
else:
    print('Oh noes! No vowels for you!')
```

Comment: This does work too, but so does .intersection(). Why should I choose any() over .intersection()?

Answer (score 0):

Checking the strings sequentially works, but if it's too inefficient for your case, you can use [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).

Answer (score -1):

You can use this syntax

```
if myItem in list:
# do something
```

also look at the functions:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: could you specify a reason why -1